Quotation marks in filenames. Can they mess with quotation marks in shell code?
As far as I know, a safe and portable filename can consists of aA-zZ 0-9 hyphen and underscore only. At the same time, if we move away from the safe file-naming practices, we can use characters such as ! ? $ % " ' / and so on.
My question is about quotes, that is, " and '. Isn't it they are more dangerous than, for example, $ or /? For example, if a filename contains spaces and we need to copy such a file, we would enclose its name quotes:
cp "file with spaces" folder_without_spaces

And because of this, I question myself: Isn't that quotes in a filename can mess with quotes in shell code sometimes?
For example, you have
aaa aaa ccc.txt
aaa "xxx" ccc.txt

and then you use
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" backup_dir; done

and then "Bam!" - something broke. Nothing is broken actually in this particular example (at least on Zsh), but I hope you understood what I mean.

No.
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" backup_dir; done would not break(*). I'll say the same I've said elsewhere: modern shells are programming languages, not macro processors, i.e. the shell doesn't just expand $f there as text, to be further processed for quotes, but just internally pass the value as-is. This is similar to something like print(foo) in Python being safe even if foo is a string that contains sys.exit(1).
There is the fact that in (POSIX-like shells) field splitting done on an unquoted $var results in something that for simple values looks like what you get when just pasting the raw value on the command line, but that's a separate function and also doesn't process quotes from the result of the expansion.
Field splitting only works on whitespace (or whatever IFS is set to), e.g. var='"foo bar"'; mv $var /tmp passes mv the three args, "foo, bar", /tmp, splitting on the space and handling the quotes as just regular characters. It's not at all the same as mv "foo bar" /tmp.
Unquoted expansions also go through filename globbing, so e.g. ? or * (and [...]) might cause problems there.
See:

When is double-quoting necessary?
Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?

Of course zsh breaks from POSIX compatibility here, and doesn't do field splitting and globbing for variable expansions. So mv $f backup_dir should also be safe(*) in zsh.

The asterisk there is that if your directory contains filenames that start with a dash, mv would try to parse those as options. There's nothing the shell quoting can do about that, as the program just gets the command line arguments as strings, it doesn't know where they came from.
(E.g. a file called -v.txt would not get moved, it'd instead be taken as the -v option for verbose mode, and the invalid -. option producing an error. The whole command would also then be missing the target filename.)
The solution to that is to either always start relative pathnames with ./, or separate the command line options from the filenames with --.  Or both, for the sake of example:
for f in ./*.txt; do
    mv -- "$f" backup_dir
done


Note that adding a / to the end of backup_dir (or use GNU mv's mv -t backup_dir -- "$f" removes the ambiguity between the move-to and move-into modes of mv. Matters if backup_dir cannot be guaranteed to exist or be of type directory.

See also a mv -t.txt backup_dir which with GNU mv would move the backup_dir into the .txt directory instead of moving -t.txt into backup_dir.
